# Question about inclusion exclusion and gcd

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

For $d_1,\ldots,d_k\in\mathbb{N}$ define

$$
L(d_1,\ldots,d_k) = \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{j+1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots<i_j\leq k} gcd(d_{i_1},\ldots,d_{i_j}). 
$$
Given two integers $n,m$ let $[n,m]$ denote their lowest common multiple. 
Suppose $k>1$ and $d_1,\ldots,d_k$ satisfy $d_i\nmid d_j$.
Then is it true that
$$
\frac{L([d_1,d_2],[d_1,d_3], \ldots,[d_{k-1},d_k])}{(d_1\cdots d_k)^m}\leq \frac{1}{2}L(d_1,\ldots,d_k)?
$$

This is related to this older question:
[Inclusion Exclusion and lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201205/inclusion-exclusion-and-lcm)